# haproxy between http-only client and websockets only backend

Tags: haproxy, websocket

odd request maybe, but I have a need to proxy between a HTTP-only client and a WebSocket-only server. these are not long-lived connections; the client does a POST with some binary data that needs to be forwarded to the ws:// server and the response back to the client. session done.

Is this possible with haproxy?

Comment: After some more research I don't believe haproxy can do this without maybe resorting to LUA scripting. I'm going to write something in python instead.

Comment: Please answer your own question, rather than commenting. Longer length limit to cite your research, and better tracking that you got an answer.